# nginx setting and codeigniter shows blank page

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

i have settings in nginx like this :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

            #kill cache
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;
    }
```

but it shows only blank page, no error in nginx log and codeigniter log..
do anyone know this?

Comment: what was your request when you got a blank page?

Comment: my request was POST @GerardH.Pille

Comment: POST is a method. What was the URI you posted to?